# Upload file to SharePoint while setting metadata and checkin comment within 1 version?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

From a web form (hosted in SharePoint) i am able to upload a document to a document library. I am also able to set meta data properties and provide the checkin comment.

The problem/question... When i do the above, it is creating 2 versions..one for upload and another when i add the checkin comment.

How can I provide the checkin comment with the metadata all at the same time as uploading the document so that only 1 version exists at the end?

Comment: can you please share the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [SPListItem.SystemUpdate(false)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms481195.aspx) for update without increment the item version

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a [SPItemEventReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.aspx) in the [ItemAdding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadding.aspx) event. There you can set the metadata in the [AfterProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventproperties.afterproperties.aspx) property of the [SPItemEventProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms439983.aspx) object, which is passed as parameter of the ItemAdding method.

```
public class MyEventReceiver : SPItemEventReceiver
{
  public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
  {
     properties.AfterProperties["MyMetadataField"] = "Foo";
  }
}
```

The event receiver class can be registered by a Feature or programmatically by the SharePoint object model on the list ([SPList.EventReceivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.eventreceivers.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

SPFile.CheckIn(comments, SPCheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn);